# How to Create two button in Bottom of the screen

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to create two buttons in the bottom of the screen using `Xamarin.Forms` and `XAML` like the image below:

[image: Example]

I've tried to use a GridView but it's getting padding and space from two buttons.
This is how I've tried so far:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" 
      ColumnSpacing="0" 
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
            Text="SignUp" 
            FontSize="Large"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
            Text="LogIn" 
            FontSize="Large"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXPtD.png

Comment: Side note, you don't really need the width to be 50*. * means take as much space as you can so if you have two columns both with a width of * each will take up half the space. Having 50* in both columns gives you the same functionality. Just an FYI

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Padding` and `Margin` properties on the Gridview and `Padding` on the Buttons to 0. IE,

```
<GridView Padding="0" Margin="0" ... >

...

<Button Margin="0" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that buttons will not provide the desired design, once it has an inner padding, rounded corners and a mandatory uppercase on text (On Android, at least) that you can't change.

Maybe using expanded labels and gesture Recognizers give you a better fit.

Try this:

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
           Text="Signup"
           TextColor="White"
           FontSize="22"
           BackgroundColor="Red"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SignupCommand}"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
           Text="Login"
           TextColor="White"
           FontSize="22"
           BackgroundColor="Green"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```